# Воспроизведение звука в xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

У меня есть приложение, в котором есть некий таймер, по истечении которого должен прозвучать сигнал. Пишу на xamarin.forms (c#), на данный момент для андроида, но приложение в будущем будет и на айфон. Сам звуковой файл находится в res/raw/audio.mp3 и assets/audio.mp3 (так и не понял, где именно должен находится файл, где-то пишут одно, где-то другое).
Ближе к делу, при использовании MediaPlayer не удается воспроизвести звук, т.к. вылетает ошибка, якобы файл не найден:

```
var player = new MediaPlayer();
player.SetDataSource("android.resource://com.example.timer/raw/audio.mp3"); //ошибка, файл не найден
player.Prepare();
```

Указывал файл по разному, начиная от полного пути и заканчивая только именем - результат одинаков, файл не найден.

Далее оказалось, что необходимо использовать `DependencyService` как указано [тут](https://wcoder.github.io/notes/playing-audio-mp3-file-in-xamarin-forms).
Но это так же не привело к положительному результату - все равно наблюдается ошибка...

Если кто разбирается или сталкивался с такой проблемой, прошу помочь)

Ps проблема решилась довольно просто. Файл необходимо было добавить в папку /assets, а в свойствах файла указать `Действия при сборке` - `AndroidAssets`. Далее все сделать так, как написано [тут](https://wcoder.github.io/notes/playing-audio-mp3-file-in-xamarin-forms).
Сам вызов должен выглядеть так:

```
DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().PlayAudioFile("Audio.mp3");
```